# Web Application ArcGIS JS API error adding layer

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I'm developing a custom widget for WebApp Builder. The widget calls a Geoprocessing service and the result must be added to map, but when I call a function this.map.addLayer() I receive the error message:

```
TypeError: this.map.addLayer is not a function
at Widget.js?wab_dv=2.6:839
at Object._successHandler (init.js:2238)
at Object._getResultDataHandler (Geoprocessor.js:11)
at init.js:63
at Object.load (Geoprocessor.js:12)
at init.js:1042
at c (init.js:103)
at d (init.js:103)
at b.Deferred.resolve.callback (init.js:105)
at c (init.js:104) "TypeError: this.map.addLayer is not a function
```

This is the snippet of my code:

```
submitGpLr: function (tab1) {
        let params = {
            json: tab1
        };
        // lancia il geoprocessing, i callback sono sotto
        this.gpLr.submitJob(params, lang.hitch(this, this.gpLrJobComplete), this.gpLrJobStatus, this.gpLrJobFailed);
    },


    gpLrJobComplete: function (jobinfo) {
        this.gpLr.getResultData(jobinfo.jobId, "Output_Layer", function (results) {
            console.log(results);
            let jsonResult = results.value;
            // function addResultToMap
            let SR = jsonResult.spatialReference;
            let GT = "esriGeometryPolyline";
            let layerDefinition = {
                "geometryType": GT,
                "spatialReference": SR,
                "fields": jsonResult.fields
            };
            let featureCollection = {
                layerDefinition: layerDefinition,
                featureSet: {
                    "geometryType": GT,
                    "spatialReference": SR,
                    "features": jsonResult.features
                }
            };
            let resultLayer = new FeatureLayer(featureCollection, {
                showLabels: true,
                spatialReference: SR
            });

            let sls = new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(
                esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
                new esri.Color([255, 0, 0]), 3.5
            );

            this.map.addLayer(resultLayer);


        });


    },
    gpLrJobFailed: function (err) {
        console.log("error");
        console.log(err);
    },
    gpLrJobStatus: function () {

    }
```

This is my setEventHandler:

```
 this.own(on(this.gpLr_Submit, "click", () => {
                let id = this.selectedMainTabId;
                let tabNewStr = JSON.stringify(this.grids[id + '_IN']['_originalData']);
                this.submitGpLr(tabNewStr);
            }));
```

How can I fix this error? I don't try the error in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I think, "this" reference to "Window" object. Your this should reference to, your widget class.You should set instance like this when, onstartup event in widget.Then you can use instance.map like this:

```
startup: function () {
    console.log('YourCustomWidget::startup');
    YourCustomWidget.SetInstance(this);
}
//Singleton design
YourCustomWidget.Instance = undefined;
YourCustomWidget.GetInstance = function () {
  return this.Instance;
}
YourCustomWidget.SetInstance = function (instance) {
  AkkrFiltrelemeVeRaporlama.Instance = instance;
}
...
...
...
...

gpLrJobComplete: function (jobinfo) {
  var instance = YourCustomWidget.Instance;
  //
  //
  //
  instance .map.addLayer(resultLayer);
}
```